# Postgres - add count of subquery along with rows returned. Very large table 5B+ rows

Tags: sql, postgresql

Users have a search feature on the site which generates a request and a subsequent postgres query.
The table selected from is partitioned and has 5+ billion rows. With this in mind I would like to avoid doing two of the same query just for one to get a count.

The user gets a maximum of 100 results at once, and I want them to see how many more rows matched their search, up to 1000, where it would simply say "1000+ matched".

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * FROM very_large_table
    WHERE foo = bar
    AND bar = foo
    AND nice >= wow
    LIMIT 1000
) AS superset

LIMIT 100
```

I would like to return the rows, but along with them, the count of rows in the subquery up to 1000.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: It isn't, once it has found 1000 rows it stops looking. There might be a million or more rows matching, it stopping at 1000 is a huge benefit on it's own. That aside I understand that 'order by' outside of that is rendered useless by not having it on the superset. This doesn't answer my question

Comment: The obvious suggestion is to get rid of the subquery and order on a query against the direct table.  But your intention here is not clear.  _Which_ 1000 records do you want from the subquery?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen The order doesn't matter, I want to return 100 rows but also have a count of how many more matched (up to 1000). Or is it the same work to select those 1000 and return all of them and have the logic outside of sql discard the 900 I don't want to show the user?

Comment: So you want to be to show the user 100 results and tell them that there are 600 more with only one query, right?

Comment: @muistooshort Yes. These queries can get very long and complex so I'm assuming running them twice is to be avoided. That's why one query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with count(*) used as a window function:

```
SELECT *, count(*) over () FROM (
    SELECT * FROM pgbench_accounts
    LIMIT 1000
) AS superset
LIMIT 100;
```